# Postgres declaration type for multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a postgres function that uses a `%ROWTYPE` declaration. When I execute this function I get a failure about returning more than one row `"code":"P0003","message":"query returned more than one row"`

I can successfully execute the query without the `returning * into assignments;` statement. Which leads me to believe the `assignments data.assignment%ROWTYPE;` is only for one row?

```
create or replace function assign(order_id int) returns json as $$
declare
 assignments data.assignment%ROWTYPE;
begin
        insert into data.assignment
        (order_item_id, pharmacy_id)
         (
               select oi.id as order_item_id, mci.pharmacy_id
               from api.order_items as oi
               inner join api.min_cost_inventory_items as mci on mci.drug_id = oi.drug_id
               where oi.order_id = $1
         )
        returning * into assignments;

        return json_build_object(
          'assignments', assignments
        );
end
$$ security definer language plpgsql;
revoke all privileges on function assign(int) from public;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The `%ROWTYPE` is not strictly necessary, but in any case it holds only one row.  You could make an array of `data.assignment[]`, but then you need to loop to fill it.

You can simplify the function as follows:

```
create or replace function assign(_order_id int) returns jsonb as $$
  with i as (
    insert into data.assignment
     (order_item_id, pharmacy_id)
    select oi.id as order_item_id, mci.pharmacy_id
      from api.order_items as oi
           inner join api.min_cost_inventory_items as mci 
                   on mci.drug_id = oi.drug_id
                where oi.order_id = _order_id
    returning *
  )
  select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(i)) from i;
$$ security definer language sql;
```

Comment: This works for this specific use case but doesn't answer the more general question of how to declare a variable for a set or multiple rows. Which I imagine I will have to ask again in the future.

Comment: @kevzettler  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22306979/13808319

Comment: also this query seems to throw an error: `{"hint":"If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.","details":null,"code":"42601","message":"query has no destination for result data"}`

Comment: @kevzettler  Did you specify `language sql`?